# Multiple image reading at the same time openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to read a known quantity of images into my program and read them all at the same time. However, I am not sure of an efficient way to make a bunch of Mat objects at the same time.

```
for( int i = 51; i < 54; i++){
        Mat edit1 = imread(fileLoc + "IMG_97" + std::to_string(i) + ".jpeg", IMREAD_ANYCOLOR);
}
```

This would only read one at a time, but I need all of the images at the same time.
Cheers!

Comment: ***read them all at the same time.*** Unless you have SSD storage it will be slower to read all at the same time instead of reading each one sequentially.

Comment: You may look at [`future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) for implementation, and profile if it's faster or not.

Comment: Maybe a vector of `Mat`?

Comment: ***Maybe a vector of Mat?*** When I replied about performance of loading all files at the same time instead of sequential, I wondered if this was the real question and was hoping for some clarification from the OP.

Comment: I am kind of rusty in C++ but that's what I was thinking of doing, can you help me out on that? As for performance, I am not worried about it, it's not going to be use for production. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
std::vector<Mat> images; // Creates a vector of Mat.

for( int i = 51; i < 54; i++){
        images.push_back(imread(fileLoc + "IMG_97" + std::to_string(i) + ".jpeg", IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)); // Adds an image to your vector.
}
```